# How can I add cv::Point to array or vector in C++ / OpenCV?

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, vector, point

I'm trying to add a `cv::Point` to an array or vector every iteration so I can use `fitEllipse` on the total data. I feel like there is a simple solution to this that I'm missing? I've tried declaring a double array but obviously I cannot convert from cv::Point to double. I'm new to using vectors and points so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why this has been down voted. I should add that I'm relatively new to this community, C++ and OpenCV so if I'm missing some obvious formatting or information in my question please leave a comment and I can make the appropriate changes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "I've tried declaring a double array" – Why? You said you wanted a `cv::Point` array, not a `double` array?

Comment: Yeah sorry I'm quite new to the C++ system of arrays, points and vectors. I was just trying to explain what I was trying to achieve from a Matlab perspective.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this out:

```
cv::vector<cv::Point> pointList;
```

Adding new point is easy:

```
pointList.push_back(newPoint); // newPoint is your cv::Point object
```

You can access to member elements in your list like this:

```
for (int n = 0; n < pointList.size(); n++)
{
    cv::Point myPoint = pointList[n];
}
```

Comment: Perfect I am from C# world, this is equivalent to a List and Add (I do not know who can imagine that push_back is Add. Thanks!